# PrimeNG menu item command binding to base class function

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to bind a base class function to my Angular 2 PrimeNG menu items.

**HTML**

```
<p-menu #menu popup="popup" [model]="exportItems"></p-menu>
<button type="button" class="fa fa-download" title="Export As" (click)="menu.toggle($event)"></button>
```

**Typescript**

```
exportItems: MenuItem[];

//Inside NgOnInit
this.exportItems = [
{ label: 'SVG', command: super.ExportSVG },
{ label: 'PNG', command: super.ExportPNG }];

//Error here 
//Cannot read property 'canvasID' of undefined
ExportSvg(): void
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasID) as HTMLCanvasElement;
    .....

}
```

I think the base class function cannot be resolved while binding to a command. Any clues how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I solved this by following command binding.

```
this.exportItems = [
{ label: 'SVG', command: (onclick)=> {super.ExportSVG()} },
{ label: 'PNG', command: (onclick)=> {super.ExportPNG()} }];
```

It seems that when binding the onClick event of menu item it works fine.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, this isn't the angular (onClick) function, as the MenuItem, when clicking it, passes in the menu item to the command.  So, what we really have here is a variable called onClick that is the menu item in this anonymous function.  The reason it's not more apparent is because the variable (onClick) isn't being used in the anonymous function.